# Is it possible to use Serilog with OpenTelemetry?

Tags: serilog, open-telemetry

Is it possible to use Serilog with OpenTelemetry?

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/logs/getting-started/README.md

Comment: I switched to using ILogger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Serilog sink for opentelemetry has been created and can be found at this GitHub repository: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-opentelemetry.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! It's now possible using [Serilog.Sinks.OpenTelemetry](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-opentelemetry):

```cs
// dotnet add package serilog.sinks.opentelemetry --prerelease

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.OpenTelemetry(endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4317")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I tried this sink but if I enable inner debug of Serilog, it throws this error when emitting a log:  
`Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="unknown service opentelemetry.proto.collector.logs.v1.LogsService")
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick()`

Comment: Looks like the receiver (collector or service) that you're using doesn't implement OTLP logs yet. If that's not the case, sharing some more details in a new post would be the way to go. HTH!

Answer (score 3):

One approach you might consider if you're running apps in Docker or Kubernetes is to just make Serilog log to console (as per [12 factor logging guidelines](https://12factor.net/logs)). From there the console logs can get received by a collector/forwarder agent such as the [OpenTelemetry collector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector) agent (or others like Logstash of Fluentd) and exported to a destination solution (e.g. Splunk or Elasticsearch). Some ways for a collector/forwarder agent to receive console logs include:

- tail and parse container logs that are persisted on the hosts
- [docker logging provider](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)
- etc.

A lot of the collector/forwarder agents like the ones mentioned have the ability to transform and enrich log messages on their way through e.g. you could reshape log messages to the Open Telemetry log data model described [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/logs/0097-log-data-model.md).

Actually I've played around with the OpenTelemetry collector agent and it does some out of the box transformations e.g. a log message of "test" received by the OpenTelemetry collector agent via the [filelog receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/filelogreceiver) ends up looking like the following after it gets exported (that is, without any processing/transformation on the way through):

```
{
  "time_unix_nano": 1637538007545231018,
  "body": {
    "Value": {
      "string_value": "test"
    }
  },
  "attributes": [
    {
      "key": "file.name",
      "value": {
        "Value": {
          "string_value": "filename.log"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "trace_id": "",
  "span_id": ""
}
```

I suppose if you were to log as JSON in Serilog and enrich the logs with trace & span IDs using a Serilog enricher similar to [this one](https://github.com/yesmarket/Serilog.Enrichers.OpenTracing/blob/master/src/Serilog.Enrichers.OpenTracing/OpenTracingContextLogEventEnricher.cs) (disclaimer this is a plugin I wrote a few years back when things were still known as OpenTracing), you could potentially do some transformation in the collector/forwarder agent to get the trace & span IDs populated correctly as per the defined OTEL log data model.

---

If you don't want to do that approach outlined above (which might be overly complex for simple scenarios) you could do some custom output formatting - see [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output) for formatting output in Serilog, and send the logs directly to your sink...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you may be looking for is a way to reuse your Serilog code to send data to an OpenTelemetry compatible endpoint (aka. Sink).
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.OpenTelemetry/

Another way of keeping your code as is, just add an exporter to #otel. This thread explains the details:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/1955

Comment: Serilog.OpenTelemetry is not open source. It has no instruction and so we don't know what it is for.